# How to create a role in Discord.Net

Tags: c#, discord

I want to make a bot for my server that, when a user types "!setlol (their name)", it will make a role and assign it to them. The role would say "LoL: (their name)". I've been trying to find documentation on how to do this, but every one covers how to assign a role that already exists.

I've tried to solve it by myself, but I just can't seem to do it.

```
var user = Context.User;
            var roles = Context.Guild.Roles;
            var role = Context.Guild.CreateRoleAsync($"LoL: {name}");
            var exRole = roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Guild.Name == $"{name}");

            if (user == null)
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("User is null u dumb fuck");
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("What u worrying about twat?!");
            }

            if (user != null && exRole != null)
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Work please");
                await (user as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(exRole);
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("User `enter code here`or role is null");
            }
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Role {name} was added to your list of roles!");
```

Image of the error in discord: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkvK4.png

Comment: [CreateRoleAsync](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/search?q=CreateRoleAsync&type=Code)?

Answer (score 2):

[Discord.Net Documentation - CreateRoleAsync](https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketGuild_CreateRoleAsync_System_String_System_Nullable_Discord_GuildPermissions__System_Nullable_Discord_Color__System_Boolean_System_Boolean_Discord_RequestOptions_)

```cs
//Context assumes that you are in a command module
//user assumes your command accepts an IGuildUser as a parameter
var role = await Context.Guild.CreateRoleAsync($"LoL: {user.UserName}");
await user.AddRoleAsync(role);
```

Comment: Is there a way to give it a color? I will try the solution later today.

Comment: Yes there is. I provided a link to the documentation in my answer, take a look at the options available while creating a role.

Comment: Your code doesn't really work :/
I was able to fix the problem by myself tho

Comment: It works under the assumptions I stated in the comments above the code.

Comment: I need your help, my code doesn't work. You will be able to see my code in the original post because I will edit it. It gives me a null exception, and I have tested it and can track it to the user.AddRoleAsync() method. I have checked everything, it adds the role to the server and all, but it just doesn't want to assign it. Any ideas? By the way, "name" is a parameter of the method and it's a string.

Comment: You should join the [Discord API server](https://discord.gg/discord-api) for more conversational help and trouble shooting. Go to the #dotnet_discord-net channel for Discord.Net assistance.